# Wordpress function is_front_page() not working

Tags: wordpress, function

I have a "static" page set up as my front page for Wordpress.

I have this in the index.php file:

```
        <?php
        if (is_front_page() || is_home()) {
        ?><p>TEST FRONT PAGE</p>
        <?php
        } ?>
```

For some reason, the "TEST FRONT PAGE" does not show up on the front page, but does show up on the posts page (as it should, for these purposes only)...I'm using Wordpress 3.0, and I tested this on the twentyten template itself!

Anyone know why?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the front page is loading from front-page.php not index.php.

EDIT

It's loading from page.php. You can read more about the template hierarchy here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: No problem. I added a link that explains all the template hierarchy in WordPress. You might find it useful.

Comment: Small correction, the front page is loading from home.php, if present.

Comment: Incorrect. home.php loads for the default blog posts view. front-page.php (new in WordPress 3.0) is the front page if you have a static page as home. The terminology is confusing, but home.php will never ever load a static page (unless the file modifies the default query).

Answer (score 0):

The `is_home()` tag actually looks for the page where all your recent posts are shown. If you are on the homepage and you are showing recent posts there, `is_home()` will return true. And if your front page is set static or template, `is_home()` will return false but will return true for any inner page where your recent posts are being shown.

The `is_front_page()` 
It returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the `Settings->Reading->Front page` displays is set to "Your latest posts", 
or when is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the current Page being displayed.

#### References

Here's [Difference between is_home() and is_front_page()](http://nspeaks.com/difference-between-is_home-and-is_front_page/)! And a reference to [Codex Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#The_Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

Putting `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` before the `if(is_front_page() || is_home()){}`

worked witht he same issue i was having